# Authenticate Web API session before body upload

Tags: iis, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple Web API 2 controller that handles file uploads. It looks like this:

```
[MyCustomAuthenticationFilter]
[Authorize]
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    private IFileRepository _FileRepository;

    public FileController(IFileRepository fileRepository)
    {
        _FileRepository = fileRepository;
    }

    public async Task<FileInfo> Post()
    {
        var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();            
        var info = await _FileRepository.CreateFileAsync(stream);

        return new FileInfo(info);
    }
}
```

It takes a streamed upload from the client, hands it off to a repository object (which talks to an Azure Storage Blob container), and then returns some data about the uploaded file. Simple enough, and it works great.

Except, the authentication filter is not applied until the client has finished uploading the file. Authentication is a simple challenge/response system using a token, so this means a client could easily upload several hundred megabytes of data (potentially over a slow cellular data connection) before finding out that their token has expired and they need to refresh it and try again. I'd like to be able to examine the request header and validate (or reject) it as early as possible, but that doesn't seem to be doable with the standard filters. I also tried creating a simple `IHttpModule` and hooking into the `BeginRequest` event, but that apparently does not fire until after the upload completes, either.

How can I hook into the pipeline such that I can validate the Authorization headers for a request before the client upload completes?

**Edit to add:**
Obviously Authenticating early doesn't do me any good if I can't also Authorize, based on the route in Web API. My service has a few anonymous methods, so I can't just blanket reject un-authenticated users. Given the architecture of IIS and ASP.net, maybe that means this just isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to make this request into a 2 stage request. One authentication request prior to the file upload request. That's a lot of baggage and the end point can't process a request until it finishes receiving it. Try a separate authorization request before uploading the file. If your request passes then you can send the file upload. Is this an okay solution?

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing now. Part of the problem is that as implemented, this upload becomes a potential DoS vector; an unauthenticated user can upload huge amounts of data which IIS will dutifully spool to disk before ever checking to see if the end user even sent any credentials.

Comment: You could implement a watchdog with the backgroundworker on a separate thread for this kind of request. Detect the request and run the watchdog. Should the request exceed a certain amount of time, size, attempts, duplicate ip attempts, too many uploads in a certain period of time, etc. You could then force the request to end. There are ways around it I'm sure.